# How can I add custom local font to Jekyll site?

Tags: fonts, icons, config, jekyll, assets

I have a custom icon font exported from Icomoon, and I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate it into my Jekyll site (I'm a bit new to Jekyll!) I've added the directory exported from Icomoon in my assets folder, and I've included the line:

```
@include embed-font ("Icomoon", "../assets/fonts/font/icomoon.ttf");
```

in my CSS, and added in my config file:

```
assets:
   sources:
       -_assets/fonts
```

but I get an error message saying: "undefined mixin 'embed-font' on line 2 of my CSS.

Does anyone know the steps I can take to integrate this correctly? Or have any resources/tutorials for this?? I feel really lost.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using @include, try @font-face instead like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Icomoon";
  src: url("../assets/fonts/font/icomoon.tff");
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_text/Web_fonts

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the custom set of icons (**icomoon.zip**) and extract to some relative location.
2. Copy '**icomoon/fonts/***' files to '***your-project-name*/assets/fonts/***'.
3. Move '**icomoon/style.css**' to '***your-project-name*/_sass/custom-icons.scss**'; note the **.scss** extension.
4. Open the '**_sass/custom-icons.scss**' file.
5. Change **all the url paths** by prepending `../font` before the `font/icomoon.*` The - * represents all extension names here.

   Example

   - url('fonts/icomoon.eot?fscaxe');
   - url('`../`fonts/icomoon.eot?fscaxe');
6. Add the relative **@import 'custom-icons';** to the main .scss file(s) to include the icons.
7. Remember the semi-colon at end of the **@import 'custom-icons';**  statement.